# Toast Push Notification Service Null Exception

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, push-notification, toast

I am trying to send a push notification and I receive this error:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code) on the "HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);" code line...

here is my send notification code:

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
        request.ContentType = "test/xml";
        request.ContentLength = message.Length;

        request.Headers.Add("X-MessageID", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

        request.Headers["X-WindowsPhone-Target"] = "toast";
        request.Headers.Add("X-NotificationClass", "2");

        var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(message, 0, message.Length);
```

Comment: Is your `uri` `null` perhaps?

Comment: Whip out {Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and check if the request is at least sent and if something is received back.